# Attempting to Determine if ISP is Blocking Port 3074

Tags: networking, internet, firewall, internet-connection, cable-modem

In the last week I have experienced problems getting onto Xbox live.  I have a wireless access point / router connected to a cable modem provided by my local ISP.  After checking the settings on my router, it appears that the port for the xbox live service (3074) was producing outgoing traffic, but no incoming traffic.  I don't have much experience with networking, but I suspect that whatever the ISP has on my modem is blocking incoming TCP packets on port 3074.

To test this, I plugged my laptop directly into the cable modem's Ethernet port and [tried both Shield's Up! and Canyouseeme](https://superuser.com/questions/10903/is-there-a-simple-way-to-detect-isp-port-blocking), both of which labeled port 3074 as closed.  While plugged into the modem I also tried the following command,

```
hping3 --traceroute -V -S -p 3074 xbox.com
```

I received the following response,

```
using eth0, addr: X.X.X.X, MTU: 1500
HPING xbox.com (eth0 65.55.42.140): S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes
^C
--- xbox.com hping statistic ---
47 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.0/0.0/0.0 ms
```

Is this the right way to find out if my problems are being caused by my ISP?  I'd like to know before contacting my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting all of your networking equipment would help. Failing that, contacting the ISP and talking to a tech would let you know for sure.

You could also try manually adding an entry in your router for said port number, mapping it to your Xbox.

Comment: I tried rebooting my network equipment, but unfortunately that didn't work.  When I attempted to port forward the required ports on my router it didn't work and I was unable to access the internet from my other devices (that's probably another question).  I'll probably wind up calling my ISP anyway, but I'd like to know if the hping3 command was used properly (and if the ISP blocking 3704 at the modem is potentially the correct diagnosis based on this result) in this situation for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

This approach is sound, one can also try from another supplier or from a proxy/VPN. Think about *all* the firewalls between the points.

Also consider trying DMZ options.

Ask yourselves, has it ever worked ?

Is that port being forwarded to another PC ?